# Power BI : How to count occurrence of value from source table?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have my data source something like below.

[image]

I need to show output in the report as below.

[image]

I tried using the unpivot column and getting something like this, how to count the occurrence value of each Business value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to remove the **Attribute** column as the next step to Unpivot. Then my table should be looks like this.

[image]

Now create a new table with following Dax function, let's say the current table as **Business Data** (*Your Unpivot table*)

```
Occurrence Table = DISTINCT('Business Data')
```

Now end result table should look like this,

[image]

You can make use of this table for your table visual in the report.

Note: You can add **n-number** of *rows* and *column* into your source table and this logic will do magic to get the correct result.

Comment: Adding an additional table is unnecessary, refer to my measure and let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Plot following mesure against Value column (from your unpivot table):

```
Business Occurance = COUNTROWS('your unpivot table')
```

Comment: This also works.! Actually, I need it in the table for a further business requirement...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have marked two places first marked place you have to add Value column then click second marked place one dropdown value is open click count menu